# php sscanf doesnt parse string properly

Tags: php, parsing, scanf, adif

I develop ADIF parser and parsing process comes to the point where I use sscanf() php function The strind that I parse is as following: "QSO_DATE:8:D>20070909" and I need to draw info from here as following: "QSO_DATE", "8", "20070909" so I use code:

```
sscanf("QSO_DATE:8:D>20070909", "%s:%d:D>%d")
```

But returning array looks like this:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => QSO_DATE:8:D>20070909
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
)
```

What is wrong? maybe there is more efficient way to parse bunch of records like these:

```
<CALL:7>EM200FT<QSO_DATE:8:D>20140324<TIME_ON:4>1657<BAND:3>12M<MODE:5>PSK63<RST_SENT:3>599<RST_RCVD:0><QSL_SENT:1>Y<QSL_SENT_VIA:1>E<APP_EQSL_AG:1>Y<GRIDSQUARE:6>KN45kj<EOR>
<CALL:5>9V1SV<QSO_DATE:8:D>20140328<TIME_ON:4>1019<BAND:3>10M<MODE:4>JT65<RST_SENT:6>VK4CMV<RST_RCVD:0><QSL_SENT:1>Y<QSL_SENT_VIA:1>E<QSLMSG:54>Thank you and I confirm your SWL report, 73's de Siva.<APP_EQSL_AG:1>Y<GRIDSQUARE:6>OJ11ui<EOR>
<CALL:5>RA6DQ<QSO_DATE:8:D>20140328<TIME_ON:4>1019<BAND:3>10M<MODE:4>JT65<RST_SENT:3>599<RST_RCVD:0><QSL_SENT:1>Y<QSL_SENT_VIA:1>E<QSLMSG:3>73!<APP_EQSL_AG:1>Y<GRIDSQUARE:6>KN85nf<EOR>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%s` means any characters, including colons, digits, chevrons, etc, except whitespace characters) and sscanf uses a greedy grab.... using more precise alternatives like `%[A-Z_]` or `%[^:]` might serve you better that `%s`

```
$result = sscanf("QSO_DATE:8:D>20070909", "%[^:]:%d:D>%d");
var_dump($result);
```

Which uses `%[^:]` to scan for any character other than a `:`

Comment: Thank you! this works. Have yet another question here how to make ":D" portion optional? I mean to make QSO_DATE:8:D>20070909 parsed by the same code as "TIME_ON:4>1349"?

Comment: never mind, just came out with the solution: '%[^:]:%d%[:>D]%s' does the trick

Comment: Still have an issue now it's a bit different but related directly. The issue is that I have the same pattern for following:
`sscanf('CALL:6>DO4HII','%[^:]:%d%[:>D]%[^[]]')
sscanf('QSO_DATE:8:D>20070922','%[^:]:%d%[:D>]%[^[]]')
`
the first one returns `Array ( [0] => CALL [1] => 6 [2] => >D [3] => O4HII )`
the second `Array ( [0] => QSO_DATE [1] => 8 [2] => :D> [3] => 20070922 )` But I need in first one return `Array ( [0] => CALL [1] => 6 [2] => > [3] => DO4HII )`How on earth to do this?

Comment: You can't use the same pattern because there isn't a `:` between the digit `6` and the `>`, so you'll need to modify the pattern accordingly

Comment: That was my original question - is it possible to do 'D' optional? Well, are there any other ways to reach the goal because I need to use one function to parse all these strings.

Comment: If you have a number of variants that you need to parse, then a regexp may well be a better option than sscanf()

Comment: Thank you, here is my answer on my question or other words - my own workaround function:
`protected function scanAdif($str) {
  list($name,$length) = sscanf($str,'%[^:]:%d');
  $value = substr($str, -1*abs($length));
  return array($name,$length,$value);
 }`